# Service layer shouldn't return ViewModels, but what if I need to return something that isn't Dbset. Do I create another Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

So I'm using this pattern on my ASP.NET-MVC5 application.

Controller <-> Service Layer <-> Data Layer <-> Database

I use AutoMapper to map between my DbSet result from Service Layer and my ViewModels in controller.

But what if I need to return custom entities from my service layer that isn't DbSet? Do I need to create a new entities to keep my pattern clean?

For example :

DbSet

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public dec Amount { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I have something like `CalculateCustomerTax(int ID)` in my service layer and this method will return 3 values which is CustomerName, TotalTax, TotalAmount.

What am I suppose to do to keep this pattern clean since returning ViewModels on service layer defeat the purpose.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are looking for data-transfer objects, or DTO's. The separation of concerns requires additional classes that your service layer should use. Your service layer should be UI agnostic and therefore not use any viewmodels.

Comment: so basically I need a DTO and my service should return DTO instead of DbSet from Database layer?

Comment: Yes. Your repository is responsible for converting the results of a database query into a DataSet. Your service layer is responsible for mapping that to DTO's. Your controllers should map those DTO's to viewmodels.